# Query with two conditions in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table `Event` and I would like to make a unique query that has two conditions. I tried my conditions separately in the console, they work individually. But I do not know how to combine them. The query are as below:

Select event with `start:timedate` above today (Event that has not happened yet)

```
Event.where("start > ? " ,Time.now).count
```

and Also would like to Select event from a specific user_id such as:

```
Event.where(user_id: "1").count
```

How could i combine them in a single query please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope):

in **Event.rb**

```
scope :filter_by_time_user, ->(userId, time) { where('user_id = ? AND start > ?', userId, time) }
```

And you can call that anywhere like:

```
Event.filter_by_time_user(1, Time.now).count
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Event.where("start > ? " ,Time.now).where(user_id: "1").count
```

alternatively,

```
Event.where("user_id = 1 AND start > ?", Time.now).count
```

You can also use OR statements.

Comment: If `user_id: "1"` narrows down the candinates more significantly than `"start > ? " ,Time.now`, then reversing the order and doing `Event.where(user_id: "1").where("start > ? " ,Time.now).count` would be more efficient.